# What do I need to get an independent developer license for CryENGINE 3?

Tags: licensing, cryengine

I have searched Google and CryEngine forums and I can't seem to get a solid answer to this question.

I have seen threads where developers are complaining that they can't sell their game because they can't get a licence after finishing their project.

Now, I am considering using CryEngine for my game because I like the royalty system, as it means I do not have to make any upfront payments but I don't want to have to get through the game and then find that I Crytek refuse to give me a license because I didn't know what the rules were, or something.

Comment: Your best resource would be the company that develops the engine, Crytek. This link provides a lot of information, and i'm sure they would be more than happy to talk to you http://mycryengine.com/index.php?conid=43

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the main source of information should be the developer's website, as indicated by @Josh, I would also suggest to take a look at [CryDEV](http://www.crydev.net/viewforum.php?f=313) and look for information about this on the forum, where myself in the past I found several threads discussing about this.

EDIT: Ok, my bad, here's more: unlike Unity, for example, you can't just buy the license and publish your game. In order to be eligible for seeking a license with CryENGINE, you must show them some demo/work in progress that might suggest that your project is worth licensing. Said that, you can read some *horror stories* on the CryDEV forum I mentioned earlier about indies who worked months on a project and they didn't manage to get their game licensed. In that case, you happen to have a product which, from your point of view, is complete, but that can't go commercial since you have no license for it, so that's kind of a limbo.

Here's a rather recent thread talking about this: http://www.crydev.net/viewtopic.php?f=355&t=116498

Comment: IS THIS TRUE? If so, cryEngine is a real nightmare! therefore is so attractive

Comment: Not sure why my answer has been downvoted twice, but I'm here just suggesting that one should not only consider what the website says, but also other indies' experience with the engine. I showed a thread that discusses about this, but there are a lot more on the web. Also, take a look at this discussion: http://www.crydev.net/viewtopic.php?f=355&t=121030&p=1198042#p1198042 . For professionals, I guess this is not much of a problem, but for VERY indies (and I mean people who do this in the free time or just started out programming games) this is something I would take into account.

Answer (score 3):

[Crytek's page](http://mycryengine.com/index.php?conid=43) is pretty clear on the subject. It says:

> If you are looking to use  CryENGINE® 3 for a commercial game or in
>   any way that is not specifically allowed in the End User License
>   Agreement (EULA), you must contact Crytek to agree on commercial terms and a license for your use.

Furthermore, the [FAQ](http://www.crydev.net/files/CryENGINE_3_Free_FAQ.pdf) says:

> We have attractive licensing options for small indie developers.
>   Please visit www.mycryengine.com to contact Crytek to find out more.

Note that as of this writing, http://www.mycryengine.com suggests you visit http://cryengine.com instead. On that site you can find a link to [register to get in touch with Crytek](http://cryengine.com/get-cryengine/register) and discuss the terms of your indie license agreement.